# Zod refine method breaking functionality

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the following schema:

```
const createTaskFormSchema = z
  .object({
    duration: z
      .custom<number>()
      .refine((value) => value ?? false, "Required")
      .refine((value) => Number.isFinite(Number(value)), "Invalid number")
      .transform((value) => Number(value)),
    checkpoints: z
      .custom<number>()
      .refine((value) => value ?? false, "Required")
      .refine((value) => Number.isFinite(Number(value)), "Invalid number")
      .transform((value) => Number(value)),
  })
  .refine((data) => data.duration < data.checkpoints, {
    message: "Checkpoints cannot be more than double the duration time",
    path: ["confirm"],
  });
```

With my form:

```
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof createTaskFormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(createTaskFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      duration: 0,
      checkpoints: 0,
    },
  });
```

And I'm trying to test via:

```
  function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof createTaskFormSchema>) {
    console.log('in here');
    try {
      const result = createTaskFormSchema.parse({            
        duration: 6,
        checkpoints: 3,            
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof z.ZodError) {
        console.log(err.issues);
      }
    }
  }
```

But the onSubmit isn't even being called (as per the 'in here' console log). It works without the refine method (goes into the onSubmit function) but just breaks when I add the refine method.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The default form values are `duration` as `0` and `checkpoints` as `0`. When you submit the form, whatever form library you are using (react-hook-form by the looks of it) will execute the zod schema with those form values; since you passed it as the `resolver` of the form. It doesn't call `onSubmit` because the schema failed validation since your form has errors. Logging `form.formState.errors` will show you those. Why did it fail validation? Most likely because 0 is not less than 0, which is what the last `refine` rule stipulates. But you should check the errors object.